# How to add additional process to [Cloud Foundry] buildpacks?

Tags: cloud-foundry, buildpack

I would like to add varnishlog logging to this buildpack: https://github.com/chregu/cf-varnish-buildpack

How can I add a second process to be started when the buildpack starts to log Varnish errors to disk/stderr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buildpack can spawn background processes. In the case of the buildpack you pointed to, the `bin/release` file indicates that it's going to launch `boot.sh` on startup. So you can just modify `boot.sh` to start whatever you want in the background with the usual shell syntax of adding `&` to the command. E.g.:

```
export APP_ROOT=$HOME
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$APP_ROOT/varnish/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
if [ -z "$VARNISH_MEMORY_LIMIT" ]; then
    VARNISH_MEMORY_LIMIT=$MEMORY_LIMIT
fi

# Start some logging process in the background
start_my_logging.sh &

# check varnish config
$APP_ROOT/varnish/sbin/varnishd -C -f $APP_ROOT/varnish/etc/varnish/default.vcl 2>&1

# TODO, Make MEMORY_LIMIT adjustable, this now comes from CF itself
exec $APP_ROOT/varnish/sbin/varnishd -n /home/vcap/tmp/varnish -F -f $APP_ROOT/varnish/etc/varnish/default.vcl -a 0.0.0.0:$VCAP_APP_PORT -t 120 -w 50,1000,120 -s malloc,$VARNISH_MEMORY_LIMIT -T 127.0.0.1:6082 -p http_resp_hdr_len=32768 2>&1
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This works for creating another process but, to my shame, I can't work out how to get the logging script to be called AFTER the varnishd process is started (I think you need a running varnishd process before you can call logging)

Comment: Would it be better to define a completely separate process/script to start logging, instead of hanging logging off the main varnish start script?

Comment: You could use a subshell that sleeps a bit before starting the logging, like `(sleep 10 ; start_my_logging.sh) &`. You could make it more sophisticated if you know of some external sign it could check for that would indicate that the main process is ready to allow it to run.

Comment: Or alternatively instead of `exec`ing varnishd at the end, you could possibly put it into the background with `&` and start the logging after that, although again to ensure the server has had time to initialize you would have to either sleep or check for some other signal of readiness.